# CSS Transitions - not working after changing size of element

Tags: html, css, transparency, css-transitions

**Background**

I'm customising a tumblr theme (Source: [hasaportfolio](http://matt.cc/tumblr/portfolio/hasaportfolio_theme.txt)), and I am trying to change the size of one particular element.

This element, on `:hover`, is meant to transition opacity - "fade in". What is happening, however, is that once I change the pixel sizes the transitions refuse to work, and the newly appearing content does not appear at all.

**HTML Code**

The HTML code this is being applied to is as follows. I've commented it as well as I can.

```
<div class="post video featured"> <!-- wrapper, no css attached -->

    <div class="box-featured">

        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/30284533" width="750" height="430" frameborder="0"></iframe>

        <div class="box-caption-text-featured"> <!-- this div and content is "hidden" (0% opacity) until :hover -->

            <h1>Paint</h1>
            <p>I hate yogurt. It's just stuff with bits in.</p>
            <p>You know how I sometimes have really brilliant ideas? You've swallowed a planet!</p>

        </div><!-- box-caption-text-featured -->

        <a href="#" class="box-caption-featured">#</a> <!-- this a is the "trigger" for the transition. Normally it would link to the post permalink -->

    </div><!-- box-featured -->

</div><!-- post -->
```

I also have another copy of this code, the only difference is that it is without the `-featured` at the end of each class definition. This is so I can see if the code works at its 'original' size (which it does).

**CSS Code**

The **original** code for running these boxes follows:

```
.box { float:left; width:250px; height:130px; overflow:hidden; margin:5px; position:relative; background-color:#F7F5F5; vertical-align:middle; padding:-5px 0 0 0; }
.box-caption, { width:220px; height:130px; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:99; background-color:transparent; filter:alpha(opacity-0); opacity:0; display:inline-block; padding:0px 15px; text-indent:-2000px; }
.box-caption-text { color:#fff; width:220px; height:130px; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:95; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; background-color:transparent; filter:alpha(opacity=0); padding:0px 15px; opacity:0; display:inline-block; -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; }
.box:hover .box-caption { display:inline-block; background-color:transparent; }
.box:hover .box-caption-text { opacity:.85; filter:alpha(opacity=85); background-color:#ff9711; }
```

My changed code is as follows. The only things I have changed are the `width` and `height` pixel values.

```
.box-featured { float:left; width:750px; height:430px; overflow:hidden; margin:5px; position:relative; background-color:#F7F5F5; vertical-align:middle; padding:-5px 0 0 0; }
.box-caption-featured { width:750px; height:430px; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:99; background-color:#f00; filter:alpha(opacity-0); opacity:0; display:inline-block; padding:0px 15px; text-indent:-2000px; }
.box-caption-text-featured { color:#fff; width:750px; height:430px; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:95; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; background-color:transparent; filter:alpha(opacity=0); padding:0px 15px; opacity:0; display:inline-block; -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; -o-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; }
.box:hover .box-caption-featured { display:inline-block; background-color:transparent; }
.box:hover .box-caption-text-featured { opacity:.85; filter:alpha(opacity=85); background-color:#ff9711; }
```

Have I just missed something dumb, or is there an issue in this code that prevents what I'm trying to do?

**Example Page**

There's an example of what I'm taking about [over here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12517063/SO/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i'm thinking at this point is that you need to change it to:

```
.box-featured:hover
```